# Is there a standard-compliant way to detect whether a function in the C standard library is implemented via intrinsic/builtin?

Tags: c, standards, c-standard-library

Is there a standard-compliant way to detect whether a function in the C standard  library is implemented via intrinsic/builtin?

I'm pretty confident I can implement code which performs better than the function provided by the standard library **for a specific call site** if only because of function call overhead. But if the function in question is implemented via intrinsic/builtin, there's no function call overhead to beat, so it would be foolish to try.

If there's a way, I have a feeling it won't be simple because it may vary by call site. For example, passing a constant length to `memcpy` may provide the compiler a great opportunity to generate inline code, but a variable length may provide a lesser opportunity. I guess the best hint available might be one of three values, "always", "never", or "sometimes". That would be good enough for me.

The details of how this might be accomplished are negotiable as long as they're standard-compliant. The version of the standard is even negotiable because that's testable and I'd be happy making the safest assumption if the question weren't answerable for an earlier version of the standard. But of course a way to do this at compile-time would be preferred.

(edited to include concrete details to make it easier to think about even though these details don't matter)

Let's assume `memcpy` is indeed the function in question and that we know the length is always variable because it was passed in to the function which calls `memcpy`, but we also know that length is frequently 1.

The overhead of calling into a library will surely dominate both `if (1==length)` and `*dst = *src;`. So the questions are how frequently 1 is actually the value, which is a question only I can answer, and whether any possibility the implementation will call into a library can be eliminated.

This question isn't about whether one can write a function which goes faster than `memcpy` or any other standard library function. There are plenty of questions on that and this isn't one of them.

Comment: No, there is no such way. You'd have to look at your implementation specs. Also, I am yet to see an inlined call to `memcpy()`, even with constant size argument. Also, what exactly is "function call overhead" you are referring to?

Comment: The C standard doesn't even *have* the concept of "intrinsic / builtin".

Comment: Even if it's implemented via builtin, those builtins might fall back to a function call for certain inputs. Really you'll want to compile your code both ways, then check the assembly to see whether there is a function call or not.

Comment: "I'm pretty confident I can implement code which performs better ..." --> Beware [Is premature optimization really the root of all evil?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/80084/94903).

Comment: Even if it's not an intrinsic, the standard library function might still be inlined, which again avoids the function call.

Comment: If you think you can improve the overall performance by replacing library functions with your own implementation then you should measure the difference and judge if this is relevant for your use case. I assume that most library functions are already optimized.

Comment: As your example of memcpy(), if you want performance then try figuring out how not to copy data at that call site. Do pointer exchange or something like that.

Comment: "Standard compliant" to what standard? Where is this testing taking place? Is the program itself trying to answer this question? When, at compile time or run-time? Is this needed to make an `#if` or `#ifdef` decision?

Comment: @SergeyA: Here the `memcpy` has effectively been inlined to a single `mov`: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/eqosd9Mv3

Comment: @rici you are quite right. I do not know what I was thinking.

Comment: Integer Poet, Consider `snprintf(buf, 2, "%d", 'A');`.  A compiler is allowed to _analize_ well known  functions and may replace that with `(short*)buf[0] = 0x65;`.  Your goal to beat the compiler is very likely non-productive.  Consider posting your _better_ code, so rather than discuss generalities, we can look at the case in question.

Comment: @SergeyA: Function call overhead includes moving arguments to their designated locations per the ABI, aligning the stack if needed, executing a call instruction (with potential effects on instruction fetching and dispatching), getting parameters from their designated locations, possibly storing a return value (depending on the function), and executing a return instruction (again with potential effects on instruction fetching and dispatching).

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: Are you sure about that `snprintf()` statement?  If you used `%c` instead of `%d`, maybe, but `%d` writes a `'6'` into the string, truncating the `5` that would appear if the buffer were bigger (since `'A'` has the value 65 decimal aka 0x41 in ASCII, Unicode, ISO 8859-n).  Or am I misreading something?  There's also a dependency on little-endianness and on being able to write `short` values on misaligned addresses (which is OK on Intel but not necessarily accurate elsewhere).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yes my example is amiss, yet the point is the compiler is not obligated to actually call a _function_, just emit functionally same code.  Yes example was intentionally  made endian dependent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the closest we'll get to a simple YES or NO answer is this comment from Nate Eldredge: "The C standard doesn't even have the concept of 'intrinsic / builtin'".